# std::string&& vs std::string_view as arguments for functions

Tags: c++, string, string-view

Getting a C2668 ambiguous call to overloaded function
for a function with string&& and an overload with string_view when using literal strings or pointer variables

With following defined functions

```
void func(std::string&& s)
{
    // use s
}
void func(std::string_view s)
{
   // use s
}
```

and calling:

```
func("foo");
```

and

```
const char* fooval="foo";
func(fooval);
```

This results in C2668 ambiguous call to overloaded function

It would seem to me that given a choice, the compiler should prefer the string_view variant over the move which requires an implicit string constructor (and memory allocation) (?)

How can I tell VS2022 to ignore the move operator for literal strings and char* variables ?

Comment: *the compiler should prefer the string_view variant over the move which requires an implicit string constructor (and memory allocation)* Where did you get that one from? Both versions require construction of an object, compiler cannot compare efficiency of different constructors - it's not its role.

Comment: Remove `func(std::string&& s)`? Why do you want to have it?

Comment: both variants serve a distinct purpose.  I can't remove the rvalue reference.

Comment: ok, I can accept that the compiler may not know whih is the better choice...
How do I tell the compiler which one it should take when presented with anything other than an rvalue string.

Comment: First thing that comes to mind would be adding 3rd overload `void func(const char* p) { return func(std::string_view{p}); }`

Comment: A C++20 alternative might be to constraint the argument type to `std::string` in the first definition (or use SFINAE before C++20). Something like `void func(std::same_as<std::string> auto&&)`. Live demo: https://godbolt.org/z/Eb8aMz1xj.

Comment: adding a const char* variant could work... but in my case it opens a can of worms I'm trying to get rid of.
Also this function can't make use of compile time string length, which string_view does...
unless I ALSO add a templated char[size]& variant

Comment: the same_as seems to works perfectly... will have to run it through the regression testing when I'm done with all the changes

Comment: @DanielLangr: Equivalent SFINAE template can be used pre-C++20.

Answer (score 3):

If you control the `func` API, decide on wether you want to have the `string_view` overload or the `std::string&&` overload, which actually should be `std::string` (without `&&`). If you want to sink the string, aka store it or modify it in some way, take `std::string` and move it into place if necessary. Otherwise, if you just want to look at the string, take `std::string_view`.

Having separate overloads for `std::string const&`, `std::string&&`, `std::string_view` and `char const*` is not going to scale, especially with more than one parameter as you will have a combinatorial explosion of overloads.

If you don't control the API you have to accept that it's a bad API and convert your string literal to either `std::string` or `std::string_view` explicitly.

### EDIT / Clarification:

**TL;DR: No additional copies are happening with my suggested approach.**

In general I strongly argue that it is hardly ever the right choice to overload functions on `std::string_view` and `std::string` (whatever the cv-ref qualifications). Either you want to *view* the string, in that case you take `std::string_view`. That is exactly what `std::string_view` is designed for and it prevents some copies that could potentially happen, eg. if you pass a string literal to an `std::string const&` parameter. And it saves you from having to overload on `std::string const&` and `char const*` (and any other potential user defined string type).

Otherwise, if you want to *sink* the string (meaning you want to store it or modify a copy of it) you take `std::string`, either by value or by reference. If you take `std::string` by reference, you have to overload on `std::string const&` and `std::string&&`, which is exactly what `std::same_as<std::string> auto&&` does. This prevents one *move operation* compared to taking `std::string` by value at the cost of having the additional code complexity of two overloads or the function being a template. The amount of copies happening in either case are the same, i.e. zero, if you already have an `std::string` object that you can move from, or one, if you have to create a new `std::string` object.

Btw. if you want to sink the string and take it by `std::string_view`, you *always* force a copy, which might be what was happening in your code and gave you the need for the `std::string&&` overload.

#### On performance

So the question boils down to wether the simplified code justifies the performance penalty of an additional move operation.

To ultimately answer this question you of course have to profile your application. However some general discussion can be had about it. [Here](https://quick-bench.com/q/S6jEdUdz8QH8QpRdnMuON8wmpF4) you find a benchmark that compares taking strings by value and by reference. The cost of the additional move operation ranges from 0 to 15 nanoseconds. The cost of the added code complexity can be trivial or substantial, depending on your function and your codebase. Eg. making it a template (with the `same_as` approach) forces you to move the definition from a .cpp file to a header. This may or may not be a problem.

However, given the ridiculously small runtime overhead of *15 nanoseconds* in the worst case, I would strongly argue that the added code complexity is not worth it *until* you measure and find the additional move to be a bottleneck of your application, in which case you can still go back to taking the string by reference.

#### Other problems:

In addition to that, overloading on different reference qualifications is realistically not even always possible in the general case. Assume you want to overload on `std::string const&` and `std::string&&`. If you have a function taking a single string argument, this may not be a problem. If you take two string arguments, you end up with 4 different overloads. With 4 arguments, you have 16 overloads. The number of overloads you need grows exponentially with the number of parameters, which in most cases is not feasible to maintain. This can of course be addressed with templates, which again forces you to use templates with its own slew of consequences.

Comment: There's a reason why I need both the && and string_view variants.
This is part of a big change to avoid excessive copying and recopying of the string contents...  hence the need for &&
But it's not always about moving, hence string_view where it then passes the string_view around instead of again making copies of literal strings.

With the same_as<> approach suggested by Daniel..
It's working, without significant changes to the rest of the codebase, and I'm getting a significant performance upgrade (which was the reason for this).
still need to do regression testing

Comment: Also, there's a reason why references exist and rvalue references were added... precisely to avoid copying the string contents.  Suggesting to just user string everywhere... while this may make the code easier, is just a really bad suggestion.

Comment: @oreubens Please see my edit addressing your concerns.

Comment: Also have a look at this talk discussion the subject: https://youtu.be/xTdeZ4MxbKo?t=1336

Comment: Finally got through all the changes and regression testing. Performance increase is noticable.

You're wrongly assuming that all overloads of a function have to do the same thing.  they either ALL observe or sink. This doesn't have to be the case.

In this particular case... it's overloaded conversion functions.
if the input is a rvalue string, I just move the content over (no copy is needed)
if it's a const string&, the input gets returned because it's basically a "no operation"  thing.
if it's a string_view (because the input is a literal or a raw char*) it needs to create a string.

Comment: Okay maybe I was a bit assumptious, sorry for that. May I ask what it is that your function does or rather your functions do?

Comment: At the core it's string conversions...  between utf8, wide and ansi.
But it has several layers of in-betweens
these are used from templated classes where the argument type is templated and the result type is known.  so there's something like convert_to_string() which is expected to return an ansi string, but the input could be any of the 3.
if input and output type are the same, then I want all these layers to just "pass through" (ultimately, having it all optimized away in release)  If they aren't the same type, then of course, it needs to have a copy made somewhere in the the layering.